# Correct Unset Cookie method in PHP with MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm setting a Cookie with the following code:(admin.php)

```
  if ($_POST['stayLoggedIn'] == '1') {
    setcookie("id", $row['id'], time() + 60*60*24*365);
  }
  header("Location: addtip.php");
```

I can't get the cookie to unset, I've searched the site and the following code should be correct but it's not working;(admin.php)

```
  if (array_key_exists("logout", $_GET)) {
    unset($_SESSION);
    setcookie("id", "", time()-60*60);
    $_COOKIE["id"] = "";
  }
```

Testing the cookie has been unset using the following code on the "loggedinpage" which would return to the admin login page if cookie was unset (addtip.php)

```
session_start();
if (array_key_exists("id", $_COOKIE)) {
    $_SESSION['id'] = $_COOKIE['id'];
}
if (array_key_exists("id", $_SESSION)) {
    echo "<a href='admin.php?logout' class='btn btn-danger btn-logout'>Log Out</a>";
} else {
    header("Location: admin.php");
}
```

Comment: How do you check if the cookie was unset?

Comment: @JohnConde Updated my question

Comment: Is the code you just added on a separate page that requires a redirect to get to? The cookie won't be actually unset until the next page load. At that point it will no longer exist and not be sent to the server.

Comment: On a side note, if you want to make a cookie expire, make the date really far in the past. It works around timing issues between the server and browser. And use `strtotime()` to do it as it is much clearer than `time()-60*60`. `setcookie("id", "", strtotime('-1 year'));`

Comment: @JohnConde I added the filenames i'm using in brackets in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't clearing the `$_COOKIE['id']` value correctly. You are setting it to an empty string. The idea is correct, but you have to use `unset()` to remove the entry from the `$_COOKIE` array. If you don't do that, the `if()` condition `array_key_exists("id", $_COOKIE)` will result in `true` even though there is no any usable value in it. And setting the `$_SESSION['id']` with an empty string as well would make the following `if()` condition `array_key_exists("id", $_SESSION)` result in `true` as well. Therefore you get the logout link.

```
if (array_key_exists("logout", $_GET)) {
    unset($_SESSION);
    setcookie("id", "", strtotime('-1 year')); // send a header to remove the cookie
    unset($_COOKIE["id"]); // remove the cookie for the remaining CURRENT http request
}
```

Not sure if `unset($_SESSION);` is the right thing to do, you might want to use `session_destroy();` instead/additionally.

Comment: Adding `session_destroy();` fixed the problem for me. Thank You